# finding the constant of a distribution

Tags: statistics

Let $Y \sim f(y)$ where

$$f(y) = ky^2 e^{-3.2y}$$   for $ y>0$ and $ 0$                             otherwise.

Part A: Find $k$.

Part B: Find $E\left(X^3\right)$

Part C: Find $E\left(e^{-3.2X}\right)$

Attempt at solution:

Integrate $f(y)$ from $0$ to infinity and set the integral  equal to $1$ to solve for $k$. Did I start it off correctly?

Once I solve for $k$ I can solve for the expectation so finding $k$ would be the first step.

Comment: You started it off correctly.

Comment: Welcome to the site: To make your math look nice, please use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: If you are familiar with common distributions, you might also recognize this one as a `Gamma` and use its proven properties to make your task easier.